# Invert grayscale using fo-dicom

Tags: image-processing, dicom, fo-dicom

I'm currently using fo-dicon to build a simple dicom viewer in C#. I am currently increasing or decreasing the brightness and contrast by adjusting window width & center values.

How do I invert the grayscale using the InvertLut class?

```
    public WriteableBitmap DisplayedImage {get;set;}


    //...
    private void ExecuteLoadImageCommand()
    {
        _dicomFile = DicomFile.Open(GetImageFileName());
        _dicomImage = new DicomImage(_dicomFile.Dataset);
        WindowLevel = _dicomImage.WindowCenter;
        WindowWidth = _dicomImage.WindowWidth;
        var grayScaleOptions = GrayscaleRenderOptions.FromBitRange(_dicomFile.Dataset);
        Depth = grayScaleOptions.BitDepth.BitsAllocated;

        DisplayedImage = _dicomImage.RenderImage().As<WriteableBitmap>();
    }
```

Comment: if your images are grayscale, have you considered switching the photometric representation (0028, 0004) from MONOCHROME1 to MONOCHROME2 and vice-versa? Just giving an easy alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the solution provided in below fo-dicom issue, i was able to invert the image. I did not use InvertLUT class.

https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/784

I had to convert from WritableBitmap to Bitmap, then again to WritableBitmap.

Solution:

```
public static class BitmapHelper
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory")]
    public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr source, int Length);

    public static void ConvertToWritableBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, ref WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap)
    {
        BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        try
        {
            writeableBitmap.Lock();
            CopyMemory(writeableBitmap.BackBuffer, data.Scan0,
                (writeableBitmap.BackBufferStride * bitmap.Height));
            writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
            writeableBitmap.Unlock();
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
            bitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Bitmap InvertBitmapPixels(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap)
    {
        var image = BitmapFromWriteableBitmap(writeableBitmap);
        // create the negative color matrix
        ColorMatrix color_matrix = new ColorMatrix(
            new float[][] {
                new float[] {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, -1, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                new float[] {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
            }
        );

        // create some image attributes
        ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();
        attributes.SetColorMatrix(color_matrix);

        var bmp = new Bitmap(image);
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.DrawImage(
                    image,
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                    0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height,
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                    attributes
                );
            }

            return bmp;
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap BitmapFromWriteableBitmap(WriteableBitmap writeBmp)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp;
        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)writeBmp));
            enc.Save(outStream);
            bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);
        }
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

To invert:

```
var image = BitmapHelper.InvertBitmapPixels(_writableBitmapImage);
        BitmapHelper.ConvertToWritableBitmap(image, ref _writableBitmapImage);
```